App hangs when resuming playback using AVAudioEngine
I have attached a fully working SwiftUI application below. For example, when I am playing Apple Music in the background and I go to the app and press the play button, I am noticing about 700 to 800ms of hang every single time. Received no answer from Apple regarding this.
And I want the app to take over the music from other apps (Basically the behaviour of what Apple Music or Podcast does when another app is playing audio in the background). I do NOT want the app to have its audio mixed with others.
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var contentViewModel: ContentViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            AudioManager.shared.play()
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: contentViewModel.isPlaying ? "pause.fill" : "play.fill")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
        }
    }
}

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isPlaying = false
}

class AudioManager {
    static let shared = AudioManager()
    private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    private let playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    
    let contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    init() {
        startAudioSession()
        setupAudioEngine()
        setupNotifications()
    }
    
    func startAudioSession() {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        
        do {
            try session.setCategory(.playback)
            try session.setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to start Audio Session: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func setupAudioEngine() {
        ///Pass in a music file to the url here
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Your song goes here", withExtension: "mp3")!
        
        do {
            let audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
            
            audioEngine.attach(playerNode)
            audioEngine.connect(playerNode, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: audioFile.processingFormat)
            
            playerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, at: nil, completionCallbackType: .dataPlayedBack) {_ in
                print("Song finished playing")
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func play() {
        if playerNode.isPlaying {
            playerNode.pause()
            audioEngine.pause()
            contentViewModel.isPlaying = false
        } else {
            do {
                try audioEngine.start()
                playerNode.play()
                contentViewModel.isPlaying = true
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Handling interruptions
    func setupNotifications() {
        let nc = NotificationCenter.default
        nc.addObserver(self,
                       selector: #selector(handleInterruption),
                       name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification,
                       object: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance())
    }


    @objc func handleInterruption(notification: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
                let typeValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
                let type = AVAudioSession.InterruptionType(rawValue: typeValue) else {
                    return
            }


            // Switch over the interruption type.
            switch type {


            case .began:
                // An interruption began. Update the UI as necessary.
                print("Interruption Began")
                play()
            case .ended:
               // An interruption ended. Resume playback, if appropriate.
                guard let optionsValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] as? UInt else { return }
                let options = AVAudioSession.InterruptionOptions(rawValue: optionsValue)
                if options.contains(.shouldResume) {
                    // An interruption ended. Resume playback.
                    play()
                } else {
                    // An interruption ended. Don't resume playback.
                }
            default: ()
            }
    }
}


I didn't get your exact requirement, however, the following can improve your code's performance. AudioManager's shared object is only initialized when you press the play button. Try to initialize it in onAppear and call audioEngine.prepare().
extension AudioManager {
    
    func prepareAudioEngine() {
        audioEngine.prepare()
    }
}

Call the function in onAppear
.onAppear(perform: {
     AudioManager.shared.prepareAudioEngine()
 })

